# Why I can't pass 'Child' class instance when switching parameter type from 'const' to 'var' in 'overloaded' method

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

**MCVE:**

The following code does not compile with error when switching the parameter type from `const` to `var` or `out` in the overloaded method `Train` of the class `TAnimalTrainer`

but it compiles if non is specified.

> [dcc32 Error] Project14.dpr(41): E2250 There is no overloaded version
>   of 'Train' that can be called with these arguments

```
program Project14;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type    
  TAnimal = class
  private
  FName: string;   
  end;

  TDog = class(TAnimal)
  public
    constructor Create(Name: string);
  end;

  TAnimalTrainer = record // class or record
  public
    procedure Train({const}var aA: TAnimal); overload; // class method or not
    procedure Train(const aName: string); overload;
  end;

{ TAnimalTrainer }

procedure TAnimalTrainer.Train(const aName: string);
var
  Dog: TDog;
begin
  Dog := nil;
  try
    Dog := TDog.Create(aName);  
    Train(Dog); // error here
  finally
    Dog.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TAnimalTrainer.Train(var aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA := nil;
end;

{ TDog }

constructor TDog.Create(Name: string);
begin
  FName := Name;
end;



begin
  try       
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Found workarounds:**

- Omit the `var`.
- Cast the local variable to `TAnimal(Dog)`
- stick with `const`.

**Question:** Is this a bug in the compiler?

Comment: Overloads are picky sometimes, you can cast it to an animal:  Train(TAnimal(Dog));

Comment: @SertacAkyuz or declare it as TAnimal

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Say no more I just understood the mistake I made in that comment

Comment: That actually works. You can declare Dog as a TAnimal, even if it contains a TDog instance. The main question is: do you want to change the instance of the animal, so for instance you put in a dog, train it, and get back a cat? Or nil, as in your code.. "Sorry mam, I tried to train your dog, but it died. Here is nil in return") If you don't want that, remove `var`, stick with `const` (or not), and you'll be fine.  You can then still change the properties of the animal you train, but not the animal itself...

Comment: If you do want to be able to actually change it do a new instance or nil, you have to keep `var`, but that limits you in the type of variable you can use.

Comment: @GolezTrol I thought When declaring Dog as a TAnimal then calling Free on Dog it would call the destructor of TAnimal instead but I was wrong, it does work

Comment: That depends on if what you call is virtual and the class overrides it. ... In the end, this is a bug.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout calling `Free` on a base class pointer is fine, since `TObject.Destroy` is virtual. This is a key requirement of polymorphism to allow derived destructors to be called properly.

Comment: @Remy I think I need to read more about the subject my delphi knowledge is getting buggy :)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Regarding your first comment, that would allow the program to convert a dog into a cat

Comment: @GolezTrol I read your first comment again and it is gold.

Comment: @David - That's correct, my comment was intended to workaround a compiler bug, to convert a dog to an animal - which it already is.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz There is no compiler bug surfaced in this question

Comment: @David - There's no question that there is a compiler bug surfaced in this question. You suggest the case without the **var** modifier is a defect, because it compiles. I suggest the other way around.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz No. I do not suggest that there is any defect at all. The compiler's behaviour is correct for value param, var param and const param.

Comment: BTW, I'd have no problem with putting in a dog and getting back a trained cat. If that's what it takes to have a trained cat, then be it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz but in that case you would end up with cat in dog variable and those two are not compatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this a bug in the compiler?

No it is not.

Although you have discovered this in the context of an overloaded method, the overloading is disguising the real problem. It will be much easier to understand the issue if we remove the overload.

So, to that end, consider this program:

```
type
  TAnimal = class
  end;

  TDog = class(TAnimal)
  end;

procedure GetAnimal(var AAnimal: TAnimal);
begin
  AAnimal := TAnimal.Create;
end;

var
  Dog: TDog;

begin
  GetAnimal(Dog);
end.
```

This fails to compile in the call to `GetAnimal` with this error:

```
[dcc32 Error]: E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
```

Why does the compiler reject this? Well, imagine if it accepted this. If it did so then when `GetAnimal` returned the `Dog` variable would refer to an object that was not a `TDog`.

To see this, change the body of the program to look like this:

```
GetAnimal(TAnimal(Dog));
Writeln(Dog.InheritsFrom(TDog));
```

When you do so, the program compiles, but the output is

```
FALSE
```

In the context of your program, the compiler is faced with some overloads. As we have seen in this example, the compiler cannot accept passing a `TDog` variable to a `TAnimal` var parameter, so it rejects that overload. It knows that it cannot pass a `TDog` variable to a `string` parameter, so that is rejected. At which point, there are no overloaded methods left, hence the error message.

Comment: one more thing why the compiler accepts it if I remove the 'var', I mean I can still do the above. (in my mind when adding 'var' the compiler will not create a second pointer to the first pointer to Dog, I think I read this in one of your answers)

Comment: Because the caller can't see the modification

Comment: I don't understand why the example you give is relevant, the code in the question tries to pass a dog as an animal. If you test if a dog **is** an animal, it is. ... You would probably argue then, the behavior when you don't use the **var** is a compiler defect, you shouldn't be able to pass a dog as an animal...

Comment: A proper example would be a function that returns a dog and a call site that requests an animal.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The example is relevant because it matches the code in the question. In the question the variable passed to the `var` param is of the derived type, and the param is of the base type. As is the case in my question. The example you propose is a different situation.

Comment: No, you're trying to fit an animal in a dog. The code in the question tries to fit a dog in an animal.

Comment: @Sertac Look closely at the declaration of the function, and the type of the variable that the user is passing. The compiler rejects those types for exactly the reason I give in the answer. Remember that the compiler rejects this at compile time based on *compile* time types.

Comment: - *"The compiler rejects those types for exactly the reason I give in the answer."* - Then the reverse should compile, no? E.g.: `procedure GetDog(var ADog: TDog);` - `GetDog(AnAnimal)` . That still fails.

Comment: @Sertac that fails because an animal can be passed **in**. The example in the question fails because an animal can be passed **out**.

Comment: Ok, thanks for bearing with me. I'm thinking one proof that this is an intentional decision can be the implementation of FreeAndNil. I mean, who wants to write code that accepts an untyped parameter instead of fixing the compiler...

Comment: ... which also illustrates how you sacrifice type safety in order to preserve it...

Answer (score 3):

Basic issue with non matching `var` parameters is the possibility that you end up with wrong type inside the calling variable.

You can trick the compiler to do that by using `absolute` keyword - that allows you to declare variables of different type that share same space - and simulate what would happen if compiler would allow you to use such construct.

Consider following example

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TAnimal = class
  public
    procedure Run; virtual;
  end;

  TDog = class(TAnimal)
  public
    procedure Bark; virtual;
    procedure Fetch; virtual;
  end;

  TCat = class(TAnimal)
  public
    procedure Meow; virtual;
  end;

procedure TAnimal.Run;
begin
  Writeln('Run');
end;

procedure TDog.Bark;
begin
  Writeln('Bark');
end;

procedure TDog.Fetch;
begin
  Writeln('Fetch');
end;

procedure TCat.Meow;
begin
  Writeln('Meow');
end;

procedure Move(const aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA.Run;
end;

procedure Train(var aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA := TCat.Create;
end;

var
  Dog: TDog;
  Cat: TAnimal absolute Dog;
begin
  try
    // we cannot use Dog here, because compiler would refuse to compile such code
    // Cat is TAnimal and compiler allows to pass it
    // since Dog and Cat variables share same address space that is
    // equivalent of calling Train(Dog);
    Train(Cat); 

    Move(Cat);
    Dog.Bark;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

If you run above code you will get following output

```
Run
Meow
```

`Dog` and `Cat` variables share the same address space, so when you call `Train(Cat)` as the result you will get `TCat` instance that you can use either through `Cat` or `Dog` variable. Basically, you will end up with `TCat` instance inside `TDog` variable.

Clearly, when you call `Dog.Bark`, you should get `Bark` as output not `Meow`. `Meow` is the first method in `TCat` just like the `Bark` is the first method in `TDog`, and when resolving the `Bark` address through `TCat` virtual method table it will find `Meow` method instead. Since both methods have same signature everything is fine if you consider wrong output as being fine.

Now, if you try calling the `Dog.Fetch`, the application will crash with AV. There are no matching methods at corresponding address in `TCat` class and you are basically calling some uninitialized place in memory instead of proper method.

That explains why `var` or `out` parameter types must match the caller variable type.

As to why you can pass `TDog` or `TCat` as `TAnimal` `const` or value parameter. Both `TDog` and `TCat` inherit from `TAnimal` and whatewer you can do with `TAnimal` instance, both `TDog` and `TCat` support it. They can override particular behavior, so your cat can run differently than your dog, but whatever you do it is well defined. You cannot end up running some inexistent code.

```
procedure Move(const aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA.Run;
  aA.Fetch; // this will fail to compile - there is no Fetch method in TAnimal class
end;
```

Of course, this does not prevent you to test for particular class and use type casts to call `Fetch` if `TAnimal` actually is a `TDog`.

```
procedure Move(const aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA.Run;
  if aA is TDog then TDog(aA).Fetch;
end;
```

However, if you abuse typecasting and typecast without checking whether particular variable is actually a `TDog` instance, you will again trip into AV.

```
procedure Move(const aA: TAnimal);
begin
  aA.Run;
  TDog(aA).Fetch;
end;
```

Comment: Great answer, I should ask more questions like this, you guys are gold when you start talking about pets and how to train them. big fan of the book by the way.